# How to use Index to combine data from 2 tables in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, indexing

I have 2 tables, one contains a list of customers(t_client) with their unique ID, the other one contains a list of promotional codes(t_promo_code).
I have created the index for both data table: idx_client; idx_code and I want to join these 2 tables so that each client can have a promotional code.

I suppose there should be something like this in SQL server?

```
SELECT *
FROM [EMAIL].[dbo].[T_client]
JOIN [EMAIL].[dbo].[T_promo_code] ON 
(INDEX([EMAIL].[dbo].[T_client].idx_client)) = (INDEX ([EMAIL].[dbo].[T_promo_code].idx_code))
```

However, I cannot find anything... And I am really not familiar with Index. If I can turn index into a column, that would be much easier, yet I don't know how to do that either. 
I only found a select sentence like this:

```
Select @row_index := @row_index +1 as index
```

But it seems that it only works for MYSQL, while I am using SQL SERVER 2008.

Any ideas?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: If the index is configured well, SQL server will (usually) choose the best plan for you and the "index joining" happens in the background. You need to join the columns in the table. Review the execution plan of the query and if it still needs tuning then modify your index. There are certain aspects of the index (ex: parallelism) that you can specify, but for your purpose here you just need to focus on writing a SQL query and less on the index usage.

Comment: Having said that, for us to help you with this query, we need to know the 2 columns that match between your 2 tables. Which is not going to be client = code. That won't return matches. Please update the post with the columns in your tables (Right click on the table, script table as, create to) and paste it in the post. Then we can help you with your JOIN query.

Comment: What does "each client can have a promotional code" mean? Please post sample data. Forget about forcing indexes, these are used automatically

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I didn't make it clear. I have the difficulty to join these 2 tables because the table t_promo_code doesn't have any column to match t_client.

Hence, I was considering generate a shared key for they by using INDEX. However, I just found another solution, that is using Row_number instead of Index.

Eventually, I have used the following SQL, and it works!

```
Select Email, 'test_campaign' AS Campaign, GEtDATE() AS DATE, Code
from(
SELECT Code, row_number() over (order by code) as row_num
FROM [t_promo_code])A
join
(SELECT Email, row_number() over (order by Email) as row_num
FROM [t_client])B
on  A.row_num=B.row_num
ORDER BY A.Code,B.Email
```